# How to select object attribute in ADF using variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to parametrize a pipeline in Azure Data Factory in order to enable a certain functionality to mulptiple environments. The idea is that the current environment is always available through a global parameter. I'd like to use this parameter to look up an array of environments to process data to. Example:

`targetEnvs =  [{ "dev": ["dev"], "test": ["dev", "test"], "acc": [], "prod": ["acc", "prod"] }]`

Then one should be able to select the targetEnv array with something like `targetEnvs[environment]` or targetEnvs.environment. Subsequently a ForEach is used to execute some logic on these target environments.

I tried setting this up with targetEnvs as a pipeline parameter (with default value mapping each env directly to targetEnv, as follows: {"dev": ["dev"], "test": ["test"]}) Then I have a Set variable step to take value from the targetEnvs parameter, as follows:[image: Set variable].

I'm now looking for a way to use the current environment (stored in a global parameter) instead of hardcoding "dev" in the Set Variable expression, but I'm not sure how to do this.

[image].

Using this expression won't even start the pipeline.
[image].

Question: how do I select this attribute of the object? Any other suggestions on how to do tackle this problem are welcome as well!

(Python analogy would be to have a dictionary target_envs and taking a value from it by using the key "current_env": target_envs[current_env].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to access the object same as you, the same error occurred. I have taken the parameter `targetEnv` (given array) and global parameter `environment` with value as **dev**.

[image]

- You can use the following dynamic content to access the key value.

```
@pipeline().parameters.targetEnv[0][pipeline().globalParameters.environment]
```

[image]